# Что означает kvm: disabled by bios

Tags: linux

При загрузке системы Kali Linux в одной из строчек заметил такое

> kvm: disabled by bios

Что это значит? Может ли быть это причиной того, что иногда у меня линукс "зависает" и перезагружается?

Comment: вряд ли это причина зависаний, но можно либо включить это в биосе, либо объяснить линуксу не грузить модуль http://askubuntu.com/questions/263179/get-rid-of-kvm-disabled-by-bios

Comment: А `VT-x` в биосе включён?

Comment: Это означает, что при загрузке модуля kvm он жалуется, что апппаратная виртуализация поддерживается процессором, но выключена в BIOS.

Comment: Нет, это не может быть причиной зависаний. Это может лишь вызвать ошибки в эмуляторах типа virtualbox.

Comment: Причиной зависаний быть не должно, подобное скорее бывает от нехватки памяти (сожрал браузер), кривого ядра (чему в kali я бы не удивился) или кривого железа/фирмвари (и это, особенно последнее, тоже не редкость)...

Answer (score 1):

Это сообщение значит - модул для поддержки виртуализации на уровне ядра  [KVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM)обнаружил, что виртуализация выключена в BIOS. В меню установок в BIOS пункт "Virtualization Technology >Disabled<" (может отличаться в различных  BIOS). Проигнорируйте это сообшение или включите VT, причина зависаний и перезагрузок скорее всего в другом.